# Why this method is slow?

Tags: c#, winforms

Im trying to use LockBits to read pixels from a Bitmap but its taking like 2-4 seconds each time.

This is the method:

```
public static Bitmap LockBits(Bitmap bmp)
{
    PixelFormat pxf = PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
    BitmapData bmpData =
    bmp.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, pxf);
    IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;
    int numBytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;
    byte[] rgbValues = new byte[numBytes];
    Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, numBytes);
    for (int counter = 0; counter < rgbValues.Length; counter += 6)
        rgbValues[counter] = (byte)tolerancenumeric;
    Marshal.Copy(rgbValues, 0, ptr, numBytes);
    bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    bmp.Save(@"d:\testbmplockbits.bmp");
    return bmp;
}
```

This : (byte)tolerancenumeric was value 10 before i changed it so i can change this value from Form1 numericupdown:

```
private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    CloudEnteringAlert.tolerancenum = (int)numericUpDown1.Value;
    pictureBox1.Image = CloudEnteringAlert.LockBits(bitmapwithclouds);
}
```

I thought using LockBits will make it faster but when i click on the numericupdown to change its value when the program is running it takes like 2-4 seconds untill the value is changed and the image in the picturebox is updating.

What is wrong with the method ?

Comment: `bmp.Save(@"d:\testbmplockbits.bmp");` looks like a pretty slow call to me.

Comment: Removed the save now i think its a little bit faster now its taking like 1-1.5 seconds delay when clicking the numericupdown.

Comment: How big is the image?

Comment: I don't think the issue is with this method. I ran a test and it's in the millisecond range. I'd bet the delay is in updating your picturebox.

Comment: Nick from 0 to 100. Using the numericupdown.

Comment: what kind of computer do you test this on, do you test in debug mode or while clicking on the compiled .exe, did you build it in release mode? this does affect how fast it will run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try refresh on your picturebox:

```
pictureBox1.Refresh();
```

Comment: i don't think the issue is to refresh the picturebox, anyway i didn't see this issue in the question

Comment: I ran the code above against a large image and it ran in milliseconds so I'm just guessing the issue is around the invalidate/update.

Comment: Nick you were right. Im afraid to say it im a shame but it seems that i have another numericupdown event textchanged event and there i was calling another method that use the same bitmap/s and when i changed the numericupdown value it was fired both events.  Sorry.

Comment: The reason i wanted to use also the textchange event on numericupdown is that if i type inside the numericupdown a value with the keyboard for example i type 70 then only when i move the mouse pointer out of the numericupdown area it was updating the pictureBox image. Thats why i was confused and mixed the events.

Comment: Glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

use unsafe, this run quick

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Bitmap test = new Bitmap(512, 512, PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        numericUpDown1.Minimum = 0; numericUpDown1.Maximum = 255;
    }

    unsafe public static Bitmap LockBits(Bitmap bmp, int tolerancenumeric)
    {
        BitmapData bmpData = bmp.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadWrite, bmp.PixelFormat);

        byte* ptr = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
        int numBytes = bmpData.Stride * bmp.Height;

        for (int counter = 0; counter < numBytes; counter += 6)
            *(ptr + counter) = (byte)tolerancenumeric;

        bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);
        return bmp;
    }

    private void numericUpDown1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image = LockBits(test, (int)numericUpDown1.Value);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You may wish to add additional details on why this works (why memory allocation and initialize is drastically reduced) and the potential downside of the "dreaded" ;-) unsafe keyword/feature.

Comment: @Dweeberly, i think there is enough documentation available on google, all i can do is warning him/her which you just did. i could copy/paste some link but that is not really recommended in case link goes dead :-)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using an unsafe context in managed code as long as you know exactly what you're doing. Sometimes it's the only way to get acceptable performance. Just keep in mind, you should be pinning things in place before using pointers to them (GC can be an unforgiving b*itch lol)

Comment: @MikeJohnson, true :-) you have to understand both, pointer and GC

Comment: You might want to check with and without using unsafe.  I have seen instances where unsafe causes code to run slower.  The bigger speed boost is probably the fact you are using "numBytes" instead of calling ".Length" on every loop.

Comment: 9 times out of 10 when you see unsafe code outperformed by safe code its because of security checks that could have been bypassed. That or crappy code.